# how to add custom header to AFNetworking upload task?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i know how to add headers in normal to GET or POST request but i couldn't add custom header to upload manager

so if any can help me in that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any of these:

`AFURLRequestSerialization#multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:`

or

`AFURLRequestSerialization#requestWithMultipartFormRequest:...`

All of these methods returns a `NSMutableURLRequest`, to which you can add the headers using `NSMutableURLRequest#setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`.

From there you can use a task, executing for example `AFURLSessionManager#uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:progress:success:failure:` or `AFURLSessionManager#dataTaskWithRequest:success:failure:` to send the request.

Comment: im using AFURLSessionManager what i can do in this case ?

Comment: You can use: `AFURLSessionManager#dataTaskWithRequest:success:failure:`,  and pass the NSMutableRequest on which you added the headers as the first parameter.

Comment: or use `AFURLSessionManager#uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:progress:success:failure:`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to add Header..

```
   NSMutableURLRequest * request;
   [request setValue:@"Add your value here" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Set field"];
```

For Example if you want to add cookie, then

```
  [request setValue:@"frontend=322ybbnbgda6382392du" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` class you can add header.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"<Your Header String>" forHTTPHeaderField:@"<Key(Parameer Name)>"];
```